# Can not create new file in the /proc filesystem from the user space in C. Is it even possible?

Tags: c, file, linux-kernel, kernel, proc

So, here is the function that should create and write string into a /proc/minifwdb:

```
int write_to_file(char* rule)
{
    FILE* fin;

    fin = fopen("/proc/minifwdb", "a");

    if (!fin)
    {
        printf("Could not open the file /proc/minifwdb, exiting...\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (fprintf(fin, "%s\n", rule) < 0)
        return 1;

    fclose(fin);

    return 0;
}
```

When fopen() is called, it returns NULL. And there is no such file as /proc/minifwdb currently. Do I need to create it using LKM, and then use it to write the info? 
I am also trying to create it from the user that has no root access. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't from userspace, but why are you even trying? What are you trying to accomplish by creating a file in `/proc`?

Comment: I need to pass a string from user space into the kernel.

Comment: Then yes, you need to do that from the kernel side.

Comment: I can write the module that will be loaded in this function using syscall, for example >syscall("sudo insmod create_file.ko"). The module will simply create a new file in procfs, and then I will write the string there. Does that sounds like something adequate?

Comment: No that's not how you should do it. also the fact that you are trying to run a sudo command from syscall you REALLY don't seem to know what you are doing. Can you explain WHY you want to have something written in the kernel? What is your end goal, may be then we can help

Comment: @AhmedMasud I need to capture incoming and outcoming network packets, and based upon the information (rules) passed in from the user space, decide if the packet should be dropped or allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files in `/proc` are used as an interface between user space and the kernel.

It is possible to use such a file to pass a string from user space into the kernel, but the kernel code that wants to receive it is responsible for creating the file.